# Server is showing 404 error. resource not found

Tags: javascript, html, github, portfolio

I tried to build a personal website following a template and the website worked perfectly locally. However, after I deployed it to GitHub Pages, I can only see a blank page. I checked the Javascript console and here is the error message:
Server responded wth an error of 404. resource not found
does anyone have a clue why
here is my rep: https://github.com/Rudra2122/3DPortfolio
here is my blank page repo: https://rudra2122.github.io/3DPortfolio/

i think js is the problem and not loading
however if i run it using "npm run dev" it is running locally on vs code

Answer (score 3):

I have looked into the issue and I believe editing your "vite.config.js" to contain the property "base" may fix the issue. Set this property to any content after the core url.

Example:
assume we have this domain `https://example.com/` and you wish to host a website at `https://example.com/aboutme`, you would set the "base" property like so `base: "aboutme",`

When it comes to your project I would set the "base" property as "3DPortfolio". Now simply re-build your project.

I hope this helps!

### --EDIT--

Upon further inspection, it seems you are also not deploying your project to pages correctly, take a look at the [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy#github-pages).